# Ramda - Accessing map's element with applySpec

Tags: ramda.js

I have the following code:

```
const commaString = "test,test1"

const getValueLabelList = compose(
  map(
    applySpec({
      value: e => e,
      label: e => e,
    })
  ),
  split(",")
)

getValueLabelList(commaString) -> [{ value: "test", label: "test" }, { value: "test1", label: "test1" }]
```

I have always wondered is there a Ramda function that can substitute the `e => e` ?

I would like to keep as declarative as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [clone](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#clone) method which appears to do what I am looking for.

Not sure if this is the only way of doing this. So I won't accept this answer just yet.

**Edit**:

Scratch the answer above, [identity](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#identity) appears to be the correct method. Although, I'll leave it, since it's potentially another way of achieving the same result.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Yatin: Those are links to the documentation for the functions offered, which seem appropriate.  But yes, as an answer, this should still provide more, preferably working code.

Comment: Thank you @ScottSauyet, yes in this instance it's not only a link to the documentation, but also a hyperlink with the direct response to the answer (`identity`) which is what will be used to replace `e => e` as it's the requirement of my question.

Answer (score 0):

While your own answer correctly identified `identity` as the likely Ramda function to use, I'm curious as to why you'd choose to use Ramda here.  Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of Ramda's founders) is a library, a tool meant to make a certain coding style easier in Javascript.  It is not a framework.  I'd suggest that you use it only when it simplifies your code.  And this vanilla version seems simpler:

```js
const getValueLabelList = (str) => 
  str .split (',') .map (s => ({value: s, label: s}))

const commaString = "test,test1"

console .log (
  getValueLabelList (commaString)
)
```

(When I've made this point before, some people have said that they were performing a learning exercise for Ramda.  If that applies to you, never mind the above.)

Comment: Fair point. I'll keep this in mind for future implementations. We have a pretty declarative codebase, I guess I've gotten so used to it that I default to using it before vanilla JS. Also, I would like to personally thank you for creating such an amazing library and the support you give.